# Jira adding active object jar 0.8.2 not possible

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-agile, maven-plugin-development

Hi i want to add active object jar in jira plugin as a dependency but found the below error on enabling the plugin.

> Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle AO.com.ao [193]: Unable to resolve 193.0: missing requirement [193.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.mchange.v2.c3p0)
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3974)
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2037)
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:955)
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:942)
>       at com.atlassian.plugin.osgi.factory.OsgiPlugin.enableInternal(OsgiPlugin.java:399)

Is it possible to achive the active object functionality from adding own jar in jira plugin.

Stuck to implement active object functionality avilable docs are all outdated.

Answer (score 0):

In jira we add external jar using command

```
mvn install:install -DartifactID="" -DgroupID="" -DrepositoryPath=""
```

but we atlassian doesn't allow to add active object jar to external dependency.
it is provided by OSgi framework.